# How to properly configure Win32-OpenSSH authentication

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I'm using PC without Administrator privileges and I need to set up SSH server. I've tried [mobaSSH](http://mobassh.mobatek.net/) and also [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) but  both requires Administrator privileges. Then I've found [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) which seems that it might be finally working. To be honest I do not actually understand why such services requires Administrator privileges because I've set up e.g. FTP server listening on port 21 with no problems but OK, back to the question.

I've run `ssh-keygen.exe -A` included in [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) which created following files in [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) directory:

```
ssh_host_dsa_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub

ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub

ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub

ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Then I've started `sshd.exe`. My first attempt was to connect with `putty.exe` using: `USERNAME@localhost`. I've used same credentials as I'm using to Windows login but it did not work:

```
Using username "USERNAME".
USERNAME@localhost's password:
Access denied
USERNAME@localhost's password:
```

Second attempt was using `puttygen.exe` to convert `ssh_host_rsa_key` to `*.ppk` file and load this file with `pageant.exe` and then use same step as in first attempt. After this the `sshd.exe` message changed as you can see but login still did not work:

```
Using username "USERNAME".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key" from agent
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
USERNAME@localhost's password:
Access denied
USERNAME@localhost's password:
```

I guess that the server is installed correctly and the problem is with authentication. How to correctly set up [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) to being able login either using password or key?

Answer (score 4):

For a password authentication, use just `USERNAME`. The `USERNAME@localhost` cannot work.

---

To make the public key authentication working:

- Create the `.ssh` folder with `authorized_keys` file with your public key in your Windows account profile folder (typically in `C:\Users\username\.ssh`).
- Make sure the only a respective Windows account has a write access to the folder and the file (what is the default access level, if you create the folder and the file, while logged in using the respective account).

---

For details on both, see my guide to [Installing SFTP/SSH Server on Windows using OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).